# Check if a player can place a block at a said location

Tags: java, algorithm, bukkit, a-star, anti-cheat

I am creating a custom anti-cheat. However, I have come to a point where I am quite stumped. I am attempting to detect whether a player can place a block at a said location, but it is becoming increasingly convoluted as I try to make it more reliable for non-cheating players. Currently, I am incorporating a raycast algorithm (using`AxisAllignedBB`) whenever a player interacts with a block (`PlayerInteractEvent`) to see if the player is actually looking at the `Block` and `BlockFace` the event says they were. The problem, I believe, is the player's direction is only updated 20 times a second where their frame rate might be much higher. This often causes (about once every 15 or so block places from my testing) the `PlayerInteractEvent` to be incorrectly canceled.

**Raycast Algorithm for finding Block looked at**

```
 public static Block getTargetBlock(Location location, Vector direction, double rangeSquared, int maxTrials, TargetMethod targetMethod) {


    Location loc = location.clone();

    Vector dir = direction.normalize();

    final double directionX = direction.getX();
    final double directionY = direction.getY();
    final double directionZ = direction.getZ();

    Block block = loc.getBlock();

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxTrials; i++) {


        final double locX = loc.getX();
        final double locY = loc.getY();
        final double locZ = loc.getZ();

        double wholeMoreX = wholeMore(locX,directionX);
        double moreX = Math.abs(wholeMoreX /directionX);

        double wholeMoreY = wholeMore(locY,directionY);
        double moreY = Math.abs(wholeMoreY /directionY);

        double wholeMoreZ = wholeMore(locZ,directionZ);
        double moreZ = Math.abs(wholeMoreZ /directionZ);

        if(moreX < moreY && moreX < moreZ){
            if(directionX > 0)
                block = block.getRelative(BlockFace.EAST);
            else {
                block = block.getRelative(BlockFace.WEST);
            }
        }
        else if(moreY < moreX && moreY < moreZ){
            if(directionY > 0){
                block = block.getRelative(BlockFace.UP);
            }
            else{
                block = block.getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(directionZ > 0){
                block = block.getRelative(BlockFace.SOUTH);
            }
            else{
                block = block.getRelative(BlockFace.NORTH);
            }
        }

        final double scalar = Math.min(Math.min(moreX,moreY),moreZ);

        Vector addAmount = dir.clone().multiply(scalar);
        loc.add(addAmount);

        if(loc.distanceSquared(location) > rangeSquared)
            return null;

        AxisAlignedBB boundry = getBoundry(block,targetMethod);
        if(boundry != null)
            if(blockFaceCollide(location,direction,boundry) != null)
                return block;
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, I doubt this is the issue. From my testing, it works perfectly fine. Thus, I think I must rely on alternative methods. Here are some ideas, but I am not quite sure they are satisfying.

**Idea: Near Blocks**

I have thought about seeing if the block placed is within a 1 block radius (or possibly shorter if I am looking at closest distance to block from ray) of the block found from the raycast, but this offers too many problems. If a player is moving their cursor from a barrier to a further out area, a false positive for cheating would be fired. On the other hand, players could still build in a fully enclosed area if they had block pillars North, East, South, West but *not* North-West, North-East, etc.

**Idea: A* Path finding Algorithm**

If I made points on the ray in the raycast have 0 G-Cost, with G-Cost increasing with distance from the ray and the H-Cost being the closest distance to the targeting block, I feel this could solve this dilemma. I could set a max G-Cost threshold before the `PlayerInteractEvent` is canceled. The problem, however, is incorporating A* with various AxisAllignedBB of blocks seems difficult. I might be able to create a grid which consists of 100x100x100 points per block, but I am not sure this would be efficient nor best practice.

**Idea: See if the player can see the block**

This would be highly effective, but I am not sure whether it would be realistic. For this, each time a player places a block I would need to detect which blocks would completely overlap other blocks in the player's interact radius. Taking all the final non-overlapped blocks, I could see if the interacted block contains these. If not, the interaction would be canceled. This seems like it might take a performance hit, and I could see how there could also be some false positives for cheating.

Comment: What version of Minecraft is this plugin for? It matters, because there's a bug which affects 1.8-1.10.2 which causes the mouse pointer to lag behind where the player is looking. I'm not sure if that would affect this, but it seems like it might.

Comment: Yeah, this is another potential problem. This is for 1.8.8

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to create a method that informs if Player and block intersects.

Sample Code

```
public static final double ONE_UNIT = 1.0;
public static final double ZERO_UNIT = 0.0;


public static Location getPlayerBlockIntersection(Player player, Block target) {
    if (player == null || target == null) {
        return null;
    }


    double minX = target.getX();
    double minY = target.getY();
    double minZ = target.getZ();

    double maxX = minX + ONE_UNIT;
    double maxY = minY + ONE_UNIT;
    double maxZ = minZ + ONE_UNIT;


    Location origin = player.getEyeLocation();
    double originX = origin.getX();
    double originY = origin.getY();
    double originZ = origin.getZ();


    Vector dir = origin.getDirection();
    double dirX = dir.getX();
    double dirY = dir.getY();
    double dirZ = dir.getZ();


    double divX = ONE_UNIT / dirX;
    double divY = ONE_UNIT / dirY;
    double divZ = ONE_UNIT / dirZ;

    double t0 = ZERO_UNIT;
    double t1 = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    double imin, imax, iymin, iymax, izmin, izmax;

    if (dirX >= ZERO_UNIT) {
        imin = (minX - originX) * divX;
        imax = (maxX - originX) * divX;
    } else {
        imin = (maxX - originX) * divX;
        imax = (minX - originX) * divX;
    }


    if (dirY >= ZERO_UNIT) {
        iymin = (minY - originY) * divY;
        iymax = (maxY - originY) * divY;
    } else {
        iymin = (maxY - originY) * divY;
        iymax = (minY - originY) * divY;
    }

    if ((imin > iymax) || (iymin > imax)) {
        return null;
    }

    if (iymin > imin) {
        imin = iymin;
    }

    if (iymax < imax) {
        imax = iymax;
    }

    if (dirZ >= ZERO_UNIT) {
        izmin = (minZ - originZ) * divZ;
        izmax = (maxZ - originZ) * divZ;
    } else {
        izmin = (maxZ - originZ) * divZ;
        izmax = (minZ - originZ) * divZ;
    }

    if ((imin > izmax) || (izmin > imax)) {
        return null;
    }

    if (izmin > imin) {
        imin = izmin;
    }
    if (izmax < imax) {
        imax = izmax;
    }

    if ((imin >= t1) || (imax <= t0)) {
        return null;
    }

    // check this baby and see if both objects represent an intersection:
    Location intersection = origin.add(dir.multiply(imin));
    return intersection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works. But I thought about using the BlockPlaceEvent and check when the Block is placed if the Player is looking at that block.

```
@EventHandler
public void blockplace(BlockPlaceEvent event){
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    int x = p.getLocation().getDirection().getBlockX();
    int y = p.getLocation().getDirection().getBlockY();
    int z = p.getLocation().getDirection().getBlockZ();

    Location lookingLoc = new Location(p.getWorld(),x,y,z);

    if (!event.getBlockPlaced().getLocation().equals(lookingLoc)){
        //flag player...
    }

}
```

Feel free to leave recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I read the question a couple times to be sure. If I understand the premise,
you wish to verify when an interaction occurs that the player is 
looking at the block being interacted with. I take it that you want to prevent "auto-build" mods or
the like that may fake such events.

The validation should be straightforward using [Player.getTargetBlock()](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity.html#getTargetBlock-java.util.Set-int-).
If the block returned by `getTargetBlock()` is the same as that reported
by `PlayerInteractEvent` you should be reasonably confident that the player is
looking at the block.